# Linear gradient does not shows in IE 11

Tags: html, css

I know what this question is popular, but I can't get it. I am not familiar with how CSS works on several browsers, sorry. I tried to use methods that are consulted in the previously deprived of topics, but I could not get it.

Here is HTML with CSS style. I am testing this in [html-editor](https://html5-editor.net/).

```css
.underlined {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
}
.underlined:before {
    width: 100%;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    height: 2px;
    background:linear-gradient(to right, white, black);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(right, white, black)
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr=white, endColorstr=black,GradientType=0 );
}
.underlined:after {
    width: 100%;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    bottom: -2px;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 2px dotted white;
}
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>CSS Buttons</h2>
<label class="underlined">Link Button</label>
<button class="underlined">Button</button>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Input Button">
```

**These two pieces :**

```
background:-ms-linear-gradient(right, white, black)
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr=white, endColorstr=black,GradientType=0 );
```

Advised to use, but in version 11 IE, but it doesn't work.
Can anyone help with this?

**Update: I have used autoprefixer to make my CSS file better, I have new CSS:**

```
.underlined {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
}

.underlined:before {
    width: 100%;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    height: 2px;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, white, black);
    background:linear-gradient(to right, white, black);
}
.underlined:after {
    width: 100%;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    bottom: -2px;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 2px dotted white;
}
```

And still, it doesn't work with a button in IE 11. I think I have used all the suggestions, mb I miss something?
Ok, if a linear gradient doesn't work at all on IE 11, can I use some alternatives?

Comment: .Gradient doenst helps too

Comment: You are missing semicolon before filter css property. Also use `autoprefixer` to write old browser compatible css.

Comment: it doesnt helps...(((9((. Also i found this https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh801215(v=vs.85).aspx, seems like filter is deprecated in IE 10+

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/), `background:linear-gradient()` **is not supported by IE11**.

As mentioned in comments by [Mr_Green](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1577396/mr-green), you should use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/), to at least make it work on browsers supporting it - what you specifically are missing is `-webkit` prefix.

Comment: I have tried to set filters and set difference between browsers, but it still doesnt works fine, in IE button like label does not have dotted linear gradient from below

Comment: You can try to set "underlined" style on button in IE for test, and see what it doesnt shows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of a button styled using css gradient.
Ive tested it in IE 11 and it worked

CSS code

```
.gradient {
padding: 10px 30px;
border: none;
color: white;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
background: rgb(169,3,41);
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;

/* Start of gradient   */

background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a90329', endColorstr='#6d0019',GradientType=0 );
}
```

HTML code

```
<button class="gradient">Button</button>
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojanti/s31qut63/) for a working demo. I tested it on IE11 and I think it works on it :/

Here is a very useful  [CSS Gradient online tool](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) that can help. It helps with fixing the necessary compatibility prefixes you'll need